# How to manage executors

Tags: java, concurrency, executors

It's not infrequent in my practice that software I develop grows big and complex, and various parts of it use executors in their own way. From the performance point of view it would be better to use different thread pool configurations at each part. But from the maintainability and code-usability points it would be more preferable if all things related to threads, concurrency and CPU-utilization were kept and configured at some centralized place.

Having each class which needs some concurrent execution or scheduling create its own thread pool is not OK, because it is hard to control their life-cycles and overall number of threads.

Creating some kind of *ExecutorManager* and passing one thread pool around the application is not OK either, because, depending on type of the task and submitting rate, inappropriately configured combination of working queue and thread pool size can harm performance really bad.

So the question is: are there some common approaches that address this issue?

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is finding a simple way to manage the life cycle of your components. If you have a simple way to manage your components and make sure only a minimum of them create threads you shouldn't have any problems. Unless you are talking about IO, you don't need more threads than you have cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create 2 or 3 threadPools that can be configured differently depending on the tasks they execute, if there are more than 3 different concurrent actions you have a bigger problem.

The pools can be injected when needed (e.g. by name), additionally I would create an annotation to execute a defined method with a specific pool/executor using AOP (e.g. aspectj).

The annotation resolver should have access to all the pools/executors and submit the task using the one specified in the annotation.

For example:

```
@Concurrent ("pool1")
public void taskOfTypeOne() {
}

@Concurrent ("pool2")
public void taskOfTypeTwo() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's about what I thought. I think I'll stick to this approach, though the Spring answer is valid as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is *Dependency Injection* or *Inversion of Control.* One of the most popular DI frameworks for Java is [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/). You build ordinary Java objects, but with either specific annotations or by configuring them in XML, to wire them together. This way, you can configure your different `ExecutorService` instances in one place, and request that they be injected (possibly by name) in the client classes which need them.

Comment: Yeah, though I haven't dug into Spring deep enough yet, it seems like it has my back on almost every point. Only, it takes some time to get yourself familiar with and set everything up and all, so I was wondering if there are options.